# How to embed a screenshot with minitest-reporters

Tags: ruby, reporting-services, jenkins, minitest

I am using minitest with Jenkins to produce test reports. At the moment I am using `Minitest::Reporters::JUnitReporter`  - https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters. This seems to give nice concise results.

The only thing missing is an embedded screenshot, specifically from failed tests.

How can I produce a Jenkins friendly test report that includes a screenshot? I am open to use one of the other `Minitest::Reporters` if it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the capybara-screenshot gem for this: https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot

Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.6.0'   
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.49.0'
  gem 'poltergeist', '1.8.1'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot', '1.0.11'
end
```

test_helper.rb:

```
# default rails test configuration
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'    

# configure webtests with capybara and poltergeist (headless)
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara-screenshot/minitest'

if ENV['HEADLESS'] == 'true'
  # headless driver configuration
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
else
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
end

Capybara::Screenshot.prune_strategy = :keep_last_run   # keep screenshots only from the last test run
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = File.join(Rails.root, "test/screenshots")   # where to save screenshots

# default test class for unit tests
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

# default test class for webtests
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Capybara::Screenshot::MiniTestPlugin
end
```